# How do I create an empty blender file .blend from C?

Tags: interface

How do I create an empty ~.blend file using C?

I need to create a blender file directly from my program. Is there a simple example or tutorial for this? Any library?

Comment: Do you want to create an empty Blender file, or do you want to create the default startup file?

This link may be of help to you:

http://archive.blender.org/development/architecture/blender-file-format/

Why don't you just open Blender, modify the scene to how you want, and then save that out to a file on disk? That way you could reference the saved file from within your C program, and add to it as you please? Or is there a specific reason why you need to programatically create the file from scratch?

Comment: emty file .blend  I need create program to produce blender object and all important setting. I canot run blender.

Comment: Why can't you run blender?  And why would writing a custom app that does exactly what blender does, not fall under the same limitations?

Comment: A dlaczego nie? Wyobraź sobie, że można zrobić aplikację webową. Możesz np. z jakis danych wygenerować plik blendera. OpenSCAD potrafi generować obiekty do druku 3D. Lepiej zrobić to od razu w Blenderze. Blender jest za wielki na serwer www.

Comment: Mając taką możliwość można zrobić interface też do innych języków np. Ruby.

Comment: Probably save your own custom empty blender file, package/embed that in your app and copy it as your new blender files.

Comment: I don't know why you'd want a completely empty file, but you should be able to create a new .txt, make sure you can view file extensions, rename the .txt to have a .blend extension, voila.

Comment: empty file is only begining ;-)